# Как объявить массив, чтобы не ругалось на выход за границы?

Tags: c#, массивы, c#-8.0, c#-7.3

```
abstract public double F(double x);
    public double[] Solve(double a, double b, double step)
    {
        double[] roots = new double[0];
        double x;
        int i = 0;
        for (x = a; x < b; x += step)
        {
            if (F(x) == 0)
            {
                roots[i] = x;
                i++;
            }
        }
        double[] results = new double[0];
        for (int j = 0, k = 0; j < roots.Length - 1; j++, k++)
        {
            results[j] = (roots[k] + roots[k + 1]) / 2;
        }
        return results;
    }
```

Необходимо создать два пустых массива. В первом записывать корни уравнения, во второй среднее арифметическое начала и конца интервалов. В обоих массивах ругается на выход из границ массива. Не могу разобраться как правильно в данном случае объявить массив.

Comment: Вам нужен не массив, а [список](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-7.0). Если возвращать хотите именно массив, то сделайте `return myResultList.ToArray()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужен не массив, а список.

```
List<double> roots = new List<double>();
for (double x = a; x < b; x += step)
{
    if (F(x) == 0)
    {
        roots.Add(x);
    }
}
double[] results = new double[roots.Count - 1];
for (int i = 0; i < roots.Count - 1; i++)
{
    results[i] = (roots[i] + roots[i + 1]) / 2;
}
return results;
```

Размер массива задается при его создании и не может быть изменен.